# F710 Controller X Input in C#

Tags: c#, slimdx, gamepad

I bought a Logitech F710 game controller with the intent of using it to control a robot. I am using the SlimDX library to access XInput through C# (VS 2012). I can get it to detect the controller, but am having problems with reading the thumb sticks. GetState().Gamepad.LeftThumbX and GetState().Gamepad.RightThumbX are returning very strange results. Rather than providing a value from -32767 to +32767 they return nothing.
However, the Y axis is returning values of either -32767 OR +32767 depending on the direction I push for the X axis. I am not getting a range, I'm getting either the minimum value or the maximum value on the wrong axis.

Thank you